# SonarQube start: permission denied unless sonar user is granted on all databases

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I was struggling to make SonarQube (v6.7) start correctly on Ubuntu server (14.04) but always ended up with a failure due to permission denied for user sonar on 'sonar'@'%'.

I checked several times to properly set all the privileges on sonar.* 
(`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar' WITH GRANT OPTION;`) but starting the server, always always ended up with the permission denied issue.

Only when set the permissions for that user on all the databases that sonarqube started fine:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar' WITH GRANT OPTION;` (note the `*.*` here instead of previously `sonar.*`)

So what's the point to have to define a dedicated user if it is to grant it all the privileges on all the databases? Is it a known issue ? This is a serious security issue according to me.

Comment: Do you have a DB in another schema also named 'sonar'?

Comment: I am sorry I don't get the sense of your quesion, as database and schema are interchangeable terms for me. But to provide more info, I have several instances of MySQL running: One on port 3306 with several databases (schemas) used by other projects + one named 'sonar' which was used by sonar <4.5 ; And another instance of MySQL running on port 4306 with xx databases + 'sonar' upgraded to work with my new sonarqube 6.7. I created a mysql user 'sonar' which I wanted to grant privileges only to the 'sonar' DB, but it does not seems to be enough for sonarqube.